# CF Hibernate only accepts arrays for IN ( x ) with named parameters, not positional parameters

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, hql

This sample code demonstrates the issue:

```
var Names = ['Jon','Anna'];

var Params.Pos1   = [ Names[1] ];
var Params.Pos2   = [ Names[1] , Names[2] ];
var Params.Pos3   = [ Names ];
var Params.Named1 = { name:Names[1] };
var Params.Named2 = { name1:Names[1] , name2:Names[2] };
var Params.Named3 = { names:Names };

var BaseHql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person WHERE ";
var Queries.Pos1   = BaseHql & "FirstName IN (?)";
var Queries.Pos2   = BaseHql & "FirstName IN (?,?)";
var Queries.Pos3   = BaseHql & "FirstName IN (?)";
var Queries.Named1 = BaseHql & "FirstName IN (:name)";
var Queries.Named2 = BaseHql & "FirstName IN (:name1,:name2)";
var Queries.Named3 = BaseHql & "FirstName IN (:names)";

var Results = {};

for ( var Item in Queries )
{
    try
    {
        Results[Item] = OrmExecuteQuery( Queries[Item] , Params[Item] );
    }
    catch (any cfcatch)
    {
        Results[Item] = "[#cfcatch.message#|#cfcatch.detail#]";
    }
}
```

Five of the six scenarios there work.

The `Queries.Pos3` does not work, despite being exactly equivalent to `Queries.Named3` one.

It returns this error message and detail:

> Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.
>
> The expression has requested a variable or an intermediate expression result as a simple value. However, the result cannot be converted to a simple value. Simple values are strings, numbers, boolean values, and date/time values. Queries, arrays, and COM objects are examples of complex values.
>
> The most likely cause of the error is that you tried to use a complex value as a simple one. For example, you tried to use a query variable in a cfif tag.

The stack trace is:

```
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage$ComplexObjectException: Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.
    at coldfusion.runtime.Cast._String(Cast.java:1036)
    at coldfusion.runtime.Cast._cast(Cast.java:192)
    at coldfusion.orm.ORMUtils.getTypedValue(ORMUtils.java:359)
    at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernatePersistenceManager.setQueryParams(HibernatePersistenceManager.java:844)
    at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernatePersistenceManager._executeHQL(HibernatePersistenceManager.java:781)
    at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernatePersistenceManager.executeHQL(HibernatePersistenceManager.java:753)
    at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernatePersistenceManager.executeQuery(HibernatePersistenceManager.java:615)
    at coldfusion.orm.ORMUtils._executeQuery(ORMUtils.java:344)
    at coldfusion.orm.ORMUtils._executeQuery(ORMUtils.java:311)
    at coldfusion.orm.ORMUtils.executeQuery(ORMUtils.java:303)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.ORMExecuteQuery(CFPage.java:8933)
```

Is there something wrong with the code above, or is this a bug/restriction of either CF or Hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate seems to use `setParameterList` to set an array as a single parameter.

The [relevant javadoc page](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html) shows [four versions of setParameterList](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection%29), but they all accept only named parameters - unlike the [setParameter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) method which has versions with arguments for both name or position.

**Thus it appears to be an arbitrary restriction of Hibernate that you cannot pass an array as a positional parameter.**

i.e. this code cannot work:

```
OrmExecuteQuery( "FROM Person WHERE FirstName IN (?)" , [ArrayOfNames] );
```

The query needs to switched to named parameters, or the positional parameters need to be flattened (e.g. perhaps using `?#RepeatString(',?',ArrayLen()-1)#` or similar.)